# What is the probability that the best candidate was hired?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations, statistical-inference

I have encountered some issues with the following question and have also seen the solution to it, but yet don't seem to understand why.

An employer is about to hire one new employee from a group of N candidates, whose future potential can be rated on a scale from 1 to N. The employer proceeds according to the following rules: (a) Each candidate is seen in succession (in random order) and a decision is made whether to hire the candidate. (b) Having rejected m-1 candidates (m>1), the employer can hire the mth candidate only if the mth candidate is better than the previous m-1. Suppose a candidate is hired on the ith trial. What is the probability that the best candidate was hired?

I am attaching the solution provided in the solutions manual. I will share why I don't understand this
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg7ao.png)

If we suppose that there are three candidates A, B, and C who are ranked as 1, 2, and 3 respectively. Then there are 6 ways (3!) for them to be interviewed which are:

$1. A,B,C$

$2. A,C,B$

$3. B,A,C$

$4. B,C,A$

$5. C,A,B$

$6. C,B,A$

I may be wrong in setting it up this way already, but my thought process was the following.

If we assume that the second candidate was hired and we want to find the probability that they were the best of the $3$ (in this example candidate C), then what I did was select the options that were still "Valid". For example, we cannot say that options $3, 5$ and $6$ are valid because the second candidate interviewed was worse than the first one. So we only have three valid opitons remaining ($1, 2$ and $4$).
Since they are all equiprobable (if they are not please let me know why not, need to have hope in humanity restored) then the probability of having the selected the best candidate would be $2/3$.

If we were to follow the answer given in the solution it would be $1/2$.

Thanks for any help a good fellow citizen can provide, I believe that my interpretation may be incorrect and don't know what other approach to consider since it seems that there is not much to grab on to.

It is in the first chapter of the book, page 41 (exercise 1.32) of Statistical Inference (2nd edition) by Geroge Casella and Roger L. Berger

Comment: Is it at all possible that the first candidate is ever hired?

Comment: Well the thing is that if the first candidate is hired, then the probability of him being the best candidate will be 1/3. Here we are assuming that the second candidate is hired. This exercise is from the book called Statistical Inference by George Casella and Roger L. Berger.

Comment: The problem is well known and analyzed... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem

Comment: In the famous version that DJohnM links to, the employer usually first picks m and rejects the first m-1 candidates no matter how good they are. Then they hire the first that is better than all previous ones. Your version differs on 2 points: 1) there is no pre-fixed number of candidates that will be rejected no matter what and 2) if a candidate is better than all previous ones the employer still has the option of not hiring them and waiting for the next one, right? Under this interpretation your solution is correct and the book is wrong, but maybe you copied the problem statement wrongly?

Comment: Hi Vincent, I checked and it is copied correctly. It is in the first chapter of the book, page 41 (exercise 1.32) of Statistical Inference  (2nd edition) by Geroge Casella and  Roger L. Berger.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer in general is i/N. Consider these events:

A: The event that the best of candidates 1 ... i is at location i.

B: The event that the best of candidates 1 ... N is at location i.

We are asked to find P(B|A). This is P(A|B)P(B)/P(A). However, B=>A, therefore P(A|B)=1. Now plug in P(A)=1/i, P(B)=1/N.

Answer (score 1):

*You have misunderstood the link, which is correct*

Let me give a numerical example first.

Suppose there are $10$ candidates, and you have selected the third (who, of course, is the best among the $3$ you have seen)

How many candidates have you not seen ? $10-3 =7$, and any of the $7$ remaining + $1$ (the selected one) could actually be the best, right ? So P(the $3$rd candidate is best $= \frac18 \equiv \frac{1}{10-3+1}$

This generalizes to $N$ people of which the *i*th has been selected yielding  $P(i) = \Large\frac1{N-i+1}$

Comment: I'm not sure it follows that any of the "7 remaining +1 could actually be the best".
Eg: say 1,2,3...,10 are the candidates and 1 is worst and 10 is the best.
If you saw 1,8 first vs 1,2 first, the pool of potential third candidates that would be better than the first two is dramatically different in these scenarios.

Comment: You can pick the first $i$ candidates randomly of the pool of $N$ people and place the best of them in the $i$-th spot in $\binom N i\frac{1}{i}$ ways.
Of these, to guarantee that the best guy made it into the pool and into the $i$-th spot is $\binom{N-1}{i-1}\frac{1}{i}$ ways. 
The probability is just the quotient: $\frac{i}{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say these are the cases
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
Lets say A is the best. B is better and C is good.
If I consider choosing the best in one and three go, then prob of finding A at 1st or 3rd position is -- 2/6 = 1/3.

But lets say we choose doesnt choose in 1st go. Instead we will choose 2nd best found or if we reach at end then we unfortunately have to choose last person.
So case 1) rejected A now B is worse so switch to C. Final is C.
Case 2) rejected A now C is worse so switch to B. Final is B.
Case 3) Rejected B, now found better A. So we stop here, final is A.
Case 4) Rejected B, now found worse C, so switched to A. Final is A.
Case 5) Rejected C, A is better. So stop here and final is A.
Case 6) rejected c, b is better than c , so stop here and finalise A.

So prob of finalizing A is 3/6 = 1/2.

Hence it is a better probability than 1/3. So answer is 1/2.

Comment: Pl. see the link OP provided, and what it is saying. His basic question is on how that is valid.